# Django endless pagination url issue on page reload

Tags: django-endless-pagination

I am using endless pagination for my django project. On a page where I display records as a report, things work well.

However, when I include some "operations" with my records, I have issues.

e.g. my table row displays information and has additional column which takes the user to edit form.

```
{% extends "base/home.html" %}
{% load endless %}

{% block maincontent %}

{% paginate 5 atlist %}

<table> class="table">
    {% for rec in atlist %} 
    <tr>

    <!-- ... Headers ... and other columns code taken out .... -->

    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="location.href='/secure/editmytypes?ID={{rec.uuid}}'">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="location.href='/secure/deletemytypes?ID={{rec.uuid}}'">Delete</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{{ pages.previous }} {{ pages.next }}
{% endblock %}
```

When the above template is loaded the first time, {{ pages.previous }} {{ pages.next }} display proper links like

```
"/list?page=2"
```

and behaves properly if I only do next / previous page navigation.

But, when the user clicks on Edit link (Edit Button) in a row to goto the edit form - do the operation and come back to this list (both the forms save data and transfers control back to this list) the {{ pages.previous }} {{ pages.next }} links become

```
"/secure/editmytypes?ID='..uuid...'&pages=2"
```

or

```
"/secure/deletemytypes?ID='..uuid...'&pages=2"
```

Does anyone have any pointers I could use ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the way my edit for returns control back to this list form did the trick for me.

I was doing

```
# return render(request,'base/list_mytypes.html',{'atlist':mytypeslist,},)
```

which was the problem .. I changed it to

```
return redirect('/secure/listmytypes',{'atlist':mytypeslist,},)
```

and now suddenly the page links are proper !!

Doing some R&D in this since I think both the shortcuts essentially achieve the same effect (I know they return different HttpResponse objects but that should not have any effect on a url in some other page - unless I am missing something here).